# CHARINDEX function to fetch string of digits until there is '.'

Tags: sql-server, azure, data-warehouse, charindex

How to fetch string of letters up to a digit before `.` using `charindex`, for example:

| ID |
| --- |
| 1022786.12 |
| 1203384 |
| 1226757.23 |
| 22343445 |
| 23434533 |

and I want to fetch only those which do not have `.`  using `charindex` function.

we can do this using `like` condition:

```
where ID not like '%.%'
```

But I want to use `charindex` function

After using `charindex`, the result should be:

| Result |
| --- |
| 1203384 |
| 22343445 |
| 23434533 |

How do I do this?

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] is this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a *practical* problem to be solved if you already have a solution but insist on using one particular function.

Comment: *"But I want to use charindex function"* Why? `LIKE` seems like the better solution here (though neither are SARGable) .But if you "must" then what about your attempt didn't work? Seems like you're wanting to check columns that contain an `int`, so why not throw `TRY_CONVERT` in there as an option too.

Answer (score 0):

use **charindex('.', number) < 1**

```
declare @t table(number varchar(20))
insert @t select '1022786.12'
insert @t select '1203384'
insert @t select '1226757.23'
insert @t select '22343445'
insert @t select '23434533'

select * 
from @t
where charindex('.', number) < 1
```